# Запрос данных из возможно не существующего(опционального) столбца

Tags: postgresql

Допустим есть таблица со столбцами: `id, name, optional`. При этом последний столбец может не существовать. Если он не существует, то нужно подставить некоторое дефолтное значение.

Что-то вроде такого:

```
select id, name, coalesce(optional, 'some default value') from my_table;
```

Сейчас я получаю ошибку, что слолбец `optional` не существует.

Возможно ли организовать что-то подобное в среде `PostgreSQL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL язык строго типизированный, все сущности (таблицы, типы данных, поля) участвующие в запросе обязаны существовать до начала выполнения запроса.

Желание запрашивать данные из таблицы не зная заведомо структуру таблицы вообще вещь странная и возможно указывает на ошибку проектирования.

---

Что одновременно с этим не исключает использование других языков: например напишите plpgsql хранимку, которая будет проверять существование такого поля и выполнять разные запросы в зависимости от этого условия. Либо какой-нибудь другой язык, в котором структура таблицы маппится в динамическую структуру и существование поля возможно проверить при исполнении.

Так же можно использовать динамические типы данных вроде `json`:

```
select row_to_json(tablename)->>'non_exists_field' from tablename;
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду думать, как организовать это извне СУБД.